# What would cause an error in authorizing payment?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, shipping-methods

I am using Magento 1.9.3.1. I wanted to add a custom shipping module and I used this tutorial- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-in-magento--cms-23747

When I use any other shipping option everything goes through. When I use this shipping option I get "Error Authorizing Payment", with no other error information. Is there something else I need to do for a custom shipping method work? I use Chargelogic for credit card payments.

Edit:
Here is the stack trace from the log-
Stack trace:

```
#0 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/code/local/ChargeLogic/Connect/Model/Connect.php(96): Mage::throwException('Error in author...')
#1 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(1089): ChargeLogic_Connect_Model_Connect->authorize(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), 288.6)
#2 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(342): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_authorize(true, 288.6)
#3 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(896): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
#4 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1114): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
#5 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#6 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#7 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#8 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#9 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#10 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(815): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#11 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(578): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#12 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#13 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#14 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /www/sites/www.site.com/files/html/index.php(84): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

Comment: Try debugging where there error is thrown and see what the message is. Highly likely the detailed error message is logged in `exception.log` or `system.log`.

Comment: Added the stack trace to the original question

Comment: step through this file `app/code/local/ChargeLogic/Connect/Model/Connect.php(96):` where the exception is thrown and figure out why it's being thrown. Can't help without the code.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this issue I hope this helps. This is on my dev site so it was set as test. I contacted Charge Logic and got this response-

"When you are using a test account, the response you receive has to do with the number of cents in the transaction amount. The system is basically in a demo mode, and that’s how you generate declines for testing and training purposes.
Amount Result Message

```
xx.00 APPROVED

xx.01 TRY AGAIN

xx.02 FAILURE

xx.03 DUPLICATE

xx.04 INVALID MERCHANT

xx.05 INVALID TRANSACTION

xx.56 DECLINED

xx.57 INSUFFICIENT FUNDS

xx.58 INVALID CARD

xx.59 EXPIRED CARD

xx.60 CALL AUTH CENTER

xx.99 DUPLICATE APPROVED
```

If the number of cents is not listed, it will be approved. Therefore, if you change your order to total to a different number of cents, you will get an approval."

I was trying to purchase an item that ended in 60 cents so the transaction would not go through.

Comment: This is different for each gateway.  Some use dollar amounts over 1000, others cents, and others you have to specify a flag.  The easiest way to see **why** a transaction was declined is to turn that gateway's debug flag on.  This should produce a log file like var/log/payment_<gateway_code>.log (e.g. var/log/payment_authorizenet.log).  That should have logged the actual transaction call and response (with PCI data removed or replaced with asterisks (*)) and you should have seen the error code there.